# Alternative Time measurements

Tags: measure-theory, unit-of-measure

Just how there exists different metric systems or ways of measuring different units. Has anyone ever tried to develop a different way of measuring time?

Does anyone here is aware of a different time system? Has anyone here tried to develop his own time system?

Thanks in advance and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

During the French Revolution, rhey propose a decimal version of Time where 1 Day is divided in 10 decimal hours, 1 decimal hour is divided in 100 decimal minutes and 1 decimal minute is divided in 100 decimal seconds.

As the rest of the metric system, it simplify conversion between units and sub-units. It also simplify date stamp. E.g. $2020-02-06.534$ could be interpreted as february second of the year $2020$, at $5$ decimal hours and $34$ decimal minutes. It is the same as $534$ decimal minutes. It also shows that the equivalent of $53.4\%$ of the day have passed

See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had no clue about the French thing, but I just developed my version of a decimal time system. Here's a link to the google sheets that I made a clock on:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AmpsVf7F89DKAShWEfu5rbmuh91MMpZL3An9bxtAG88/edit?usp=sharing

It's not perfect yet, but it is really interesting. For example, by looking at the time you can tell the exact percentage of the day. 8:42:12 would mean you were 84.212% done with the day. Instead of Hours: Minutes: Seconds, I labeled my system Fricks: Clicks: Ticks. Additionally, months don't exist. You just refer to the date as the day in the year. Like January 26 would just be Day 26. Or February 1 would be Day 32.